Is there a way to filter out .pstats based on a directory?
I am trying to profile the nerfstudio implementation of the method nerfacto. I used cprofile while the running the scripts and then used the .pstats file generated by Cprofile to visualize the results with Snakeviz.
Visualization using snakeviz
I did:
python -m cProfile -o profile_data.profile $(which ns-train) nerfacto --data poster

then :
py -m snakeviz profile_data.profile

the project can be executed using : ns-train <method_name> --data <data_folder>, with ns-train the binary leading to the entrypoint of the project.
The problem I am facing is that I have a loot of methods shown (~20000), this is due to Cprofile which outputs even the python and pytorch built in methods and not only the relevant methods I want to profile.
I was wondering if there is a way to filter the profiling results by directory. Or if there are any other alternatives that can make profiling a project of this size easier.
Thank you
